# How to get handle on wrapped class

Tags: c#, class, wrapper, unmanaged

If I have a class that wraps another, i.e.:

```
public class NoWrap
{
  internal sealed class Wrapped
  { //Constructor here
  }
}
```

How can I get a handle on the instance of the `Wrapped` class from inside the `NoWrap` class?

Answer (score 0):

The instance of the `Wrapped` class will be present only if you create it explicitly. It won't start to exist automatically when `NoWrap` is being created. For example:

```
public class NoWrap
{
    internal sealed class Wrapped
    {
    }

    public void Wrap()
    {
        this.wrapped = new Wrapped();
    }

    internal Wrapped GetWrapped()     //note: cannot be public
    {
        return wrapped;
    }

    private Wrapped wrapped;
}

//...

NoWrap nw = new NoWrap();  // (*)

nw.Wrap();                 // (**)
```

At point marked with (*) one instance of `NoWrap` exists, and no instances of `Wrapped`. Only after `Wrap` was called in (**), an instance of `Wrapped` is created, and the fact whether you have a reference to it or not depends entirely on you - i.e. you have to assign it to some variable/field/property.

To use it outside the `NoWrap` class:

```
NoWrap.Wrapped x = nw.GetWrapped();
```